# Problem in updating DE using SSJS

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

We are trying to fetch Promo Code for each customer and updating the issued promo code status to true in DE. While updating we noticed the update row count is -1, still the DE is getting updated. Because of this we are not able to use new promo codes. Please find below the code sample:

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("core","1");
var dePromoCodes = DataExtension.Init("PROMO_CODE_TESTDM");
var deAudience = DataExtension.Init("DMTEST_BD_AUD_1");
var audienceFilter = {
                     Property:"is_processed",
                     SimpleOperator:"equals",
                     Value:"N"
                 };
var objSubscribers = deAudience.Rows.Retrieve(audienceFilter);
var intNumSubs = objSubscribers.length;

Write("Count : " + intNumSubs + "</br>");
try{
 for (var intSubCount = 0; intSubCount < intNumSubs; intSubCount++){
  var objSubscriber = objSubscribers[intSubCount]
   var complexfilter = {
                 LeftOperand:{
                     Property:"is_claimed",
                     SimpleOperator:"equals",
                     Value:'false'
                 },
                 LogicalOperator:"AND",
                 RightOperand:{
                     Property:"campaign_code",
                     SimpleOperator:"equals",
                     Value: objSubscriber.campaign_unique_code
         }};

  var coupon_rows = Platform.Function.LookupRows('PROMO_CODE_TESTDM','is_claimed','false');
  Write("coupon_rows count : "+coupon_rows.length+"</br>")
  var coupon_row = coupon_rows[0];
  Write("customer_id : " +intSubCount+" "+ objSubscriber.customer_id+ "</br>");
  Write("Coupon : " +intSubCount+" "+ coupon_row.coupon_id+ "</br>");  
  var updatecount = Platform.Function.UpdateData("PROMO_CODE_TESTDM",["coupon_id"],[coupon_row.coupon_id],["is_claimed"],["true"]);
  Write("updatecount : " +" "+ updatecount.length+ "</br>");   
 }
 Write("Done");
}
catch (ex) {
 Write("An error has occurred: " + Stringify(ex));
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ClaimRowValue function for this kind of issues to make everything easier. It simply assigns the coupon code to a user when the code is executed and changes the value from False to True.

You can check here:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/claimrowvalue.htm

Example code:

```
SET @coupon = ClaimRowValue('PROMO_CODE_TESTDM', 'coupon_id', 'is_processed', 'False', 'customer_id', _subscriberkey)
```